setting Gazebo service call from inside a ROS2 node using gz-ros-bridge through yaml file(Jazzy & Harmonic)
I'm currently working on a project using ROS2 Jazzy and Gazebo Harmonic, and I'm trying to control the simulation's pause and unpause functionality directly from a ROS2 node.
I'd like to set up gz-ros-bridge using a taml file, in order to do that,
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.
there is supposed to be a way, maybe, by the content of this page:
https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/ros2/ros_gz_interfaces
I know I can use something like this
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /world/empty/control@ros_gz_interfaces/srv/ControlWorld
and it works, but I want to be able to set it all in the yaml file, and call that in my launch file.
If anyone has experience with this or can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate your insights!
